# DynamoDB - how to read a record by primary key values?

Tags: node.js, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm trying to get an item from a DynamoDB table, but this error "ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema" keeps happening.
These are the parameters i created the table:

```
TableName : "Users-test",
    KeySchema: [
        { AttributeName: "id", KeyType: "HASH"},  //Partition key
        { AttributeName: "email", KeyType: "RANGE" }  //Sort key
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [
        { AttributeName: "id", AttributeType: "S" },
        { AttributeName: "email", AttributeType: "S" }
    ]
```

And i'm trying to access the data like this:

```
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const params = {
        TableName: 'Users-test',
        Key:{
            id: "someID",
            email: "example@example.com"
        }
    };
docClient.get(params, function...
```

I know the record exists on the database and i can filter by id using the aws console, but actually using code i cannot get a record using the primary key, i tried to remove the "email" field from params variable, but it returned the same error.

Comment: Have you tried quoting the attribute names, e.g. `"id": "someID"`?

Comment: Yeah, i tried this =/

Answer (score 1):

You can this,

```
const config = {
   region: 'eu-central-1'
};
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(config);
const params = {
    TableName: 'Users-test',
    Key:{
        "someId",
        "example@example.com"
    }
};
docClient.get(params, function...
```

Also, you can make your function async

```
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(config);
const params = {
    TableName: 'Users-test',
    Key:{
        "someId",
        "example@example.com"
    }
};
const result = await docClient.get(params).promise();
```